# How do I make a class whose interface matches double, but upon which templates can be specialized?

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates

How do I make a class whose interface matches double, but whose templated types do not dynamic cast to double?

The reason is that I have a run-time type system, and I want to be able to have a type that works just like double:

```
template<int min_value, int max_value>
class BoundedDouble: public double {};
```

And then use template specialization to get run-time information about that type:

```
template<typename T>
class Type { etc. }

template<int min_value, int max_value>
class Type<BoundedDouble<min_value, max_value>> { int min() const { return min_value; } etc. }
```

But, you can't inherit from double...

Comment: Don't try -- you'll only cause other maintainers' eyes to bleed. If you need something like this, use composition rather than inheritance, and use an explicit conversion function .. i.e. ToDouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't derive from native types.  Use composition instead:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename Type = double, const Type& Min = -10.0, const Type& Max = 10.0> class Bounded
{
public:
    Bounded() {};
    Bounded(const Type& rhs) : val_(rhs) 
    { 
        if(rhs > Max || rhs < Min) 
            throw logic_error("Out Of Bounds"); 
    }

    operator Type () const 
    { 
        return val_; 
    }

    Type val_;
};


int main()
{
    typedef Bounded<double, -10.0, 10.0> double_10;
    double_10 d(-4.2);
    cout << "d = " << d << "\n";
    double d_prime = d;
    cout << "d_prime = " << d_prime << "\n";
    double_10 d2(-42.0);
    cout << "d2 = " << d << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
d = -4.2
d_prime = -4.2
```