# Why we use non-type template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, arguments

I understand the concept but i don't know why i require to use non-type template arguments ?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are many use-cases, so let's look at a couple of situations where they are indispensable:

- Fixed sized array or [matrix](http://project-mathlibs.web.cern.ch/project-mathlibs/sw/html/SMatrixDoc.html) classes, see for example C++11 [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [boost::array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/array.html).
- A possible implementation of [std::begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) for arrays, or any code that needs the size of a fixed size C style array, for example:

return the size of an array:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N>
unsigned int size(T const (&)[N])
{
  return N;
}
```

They are also extremely useful in template metaprogramming.

Answer (score 3):

A real-world example comes from combining non-type template arguments with template argument deduction to deduce the size of an array:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N>
void print_array(T const (&arr)[N])       // both T and N are deduced
{
    std::cout << "[";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i != N; ++i)
    {
        if (i != 0) { std::cout << ", ";
        std::cout << arr[i];
    }
    std::cout << "]";
}

int main()
{
    double x[] = { 1.5, -7.125, 0, std::sin(0.5) };
    print_array(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To program at compile-time. Consider the [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming#Compile-time_class_generation) example,

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial {
    enum { value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};

// Factorial<4>::value == 24
// Factorial<0>::value == 1
const int x = Factorial<4>::value; // == 24
const int y = Factorial<0>::value; // == 1
```

There are a bunch of other examples on the WikiPedia page.

## EDIT

As mentioned in the comments, the above example demonstrates ***what can be done*** rather than ***what people use in real projects***.

Comment: I don't know about you, but "we" don't use it to program at compile time. :\

Comment: That merely demonstrates how powerful templates are, but does not show how they get used in real code.

Comment: I have seen a `Bounded Integer` class somewhere in *SO* but cannot find it now. It allowed custom type creations such as `bounded<0, 255>`.

Comment: @Hindol Do you mean http://stackoverflow.com/a/148693/743382 ? Or perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/3058733/743382 ?

Comment: @hwd The first link is the closest. But I remember seeing a more _complete_ implementation of the same with `type conversions` and stuff such that a `bounded<int, ...>` worked perfectly like an `int`.

Comment: I actually do stuff like this in real projects, these techniques are more than purely academic.

Comment: @juanchopanza Fair enough, though I still suppose that's still far from the most common use.

Answer (score 0):

Another example of non type argument is:

```
template <int N>
struct A
{
    // Other fields.
    int data[N];
};
```

Here the length of the data field is parameterised. Different instantiations of this struct can have different lengths of their arrays.