# Labeling classes to disallow operations

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to be able to use compile time information to prevent two objects of the same class being combined. In particular if `a` represents meters, and `b` uses centimeters I want the compiler to not allow their combination.

Can I do this with protected inheritance? Do I need to use Tags?

Something like this?

```
struct Meters{};
struct Centimeters{};

template < typename Units >
class DimensionedLength : protected Length {
 // What do I need to put in here?
}

int main(){

{
 Length a(0.0), b(1.0), c(2.0);

 std::cout << a+b << std::endl; // fine
 std::cout << a+c << std::endl; // fine
}


{
 DimensionedLength<Meters> a(0.0), b(1.0);
 DimensionedLength<Centimeters> c(2.0);

 std::cout << a+b << std::endl; // fine
 std::cout << a+c << std::endl; // compile error!
}

 return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the class template should look like this:

```
template<typename Units>
struct DimensionedDouble {
    double value;
};
```

and then you need to implement all the arithmetic operators for it, i.e.:

```
template<typename Units>
DimensionedDouble<Units> operator+(DimensionedDouble<Units> x, DimensionedDouble<Units> y) {
    return {x.value + y.value};
}
```

and so on. The overload can only be called when the `Units` match, otherwise there will be an error.

Depending on how close you want to get the syntax to the fundamental type's, you might also want to add constructors from `double`, etc., to your class. As shown above, only aggregate initialization from `double` (with `{...}` or `= {...}`) is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I had tried to simplify things and just made it more confusing. I fixed the question to try incorporate a bit more information, in particular there is a class from an external library that I am trying to wrap which is a little more complicated than double (Eigen::Vector3d if that means anything).

Comment: searching a bit further based on your response, would something like this work?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058561/how-do-i-make-a-class-whose-interface-matches-double-but-upon-which-templates-c

Comment: @rhetorical5  No that answer does not prevent adding differently tagged types at all.

Comment: @rhetorical5 If you want to reliably prevent implicit conversion between the types or back to the underlying type, you need to copy the whole interface in the way I showed you. There is no other way. What you want is also known as a "strong type".